# Sympy: Integral(0, (R, b, r)) not simplifying to zero when stemming from the Leibniz rule

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am differentiating under an integral. Since the integrand does not depend explicitly on the variable, the corresponding term from the Leibniz rule would not show up.
Nevertheless, sympy does not simplify it to zero. Why is that? Can it be somehow coerced to do so?
That is preventing further simplification of my expressions down the road.
This is my MCVE.

```
# Test: Check why integrating the null function does not simplify to zero
r = sym.symbols('r', real=True, positive=True)
b = sym.symbols('b', real=True, positive=True)
# Dummy integration variable
R = sym.symbols('R', real=True, positive=True)

# 1. Simple integral... simplifies ok
i1s = sym.simplify(sym.integrate(0, (R, b, r)))
print('i1s =', i1s)

# 2. Integral stemming from Leibniz rule... does not simplify
p = sym.Function('p', real=True)
i2s = sym.simplify(sym.integrate(R*p(R), (R, b, r)))
print('i2s =', i2s)
i3s = sym.simplify(sym.diff(i2s, r))
print('i3s =', i3s)
```

which produces

```
i1s = 0
i2s = Integral(R*p(R), (R, b, r))
i3s = r*p(r) + Integral(0, (R, b, r))
```

I would expect

```
i3s = r*p(r)
```

Note: all uses of `sym.simplify` turn out to be superfluous here.

Comment: What version are you using? I just tried it on 1.11.1 and it dropped the 0 term. You can also try adding `.doit()` to the end of the `i3s` line.

Comment: @jared - I have 1.1.1.
`doit()` did the job.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Version 1.1.1 is several years old at this point -- I think you should consider updating to a more recent version, as there have been many improvements.

Comment: That's what I got from an installation of anaconda for Windows.
At this point I am not sure, but I think I had to downgrade scipy due to compatibility with other packages. AFAIK, versioning and dependencies are clumsy in conda, often times requiring downgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in version 1.11.1 and the 0 term was dropped. I'm not sure at what version this changed, but you should consider upgrading. For now, you can add `.doit()` to the end of the `i3s` line to have sympy evaluate the 0 integral.