# Sympy: Get the solutions of an ODE as Function objects

Tags: python, sympy, differentiation, symbolic-integration

As a follow-up of [Extract the two functions solutions of a homogeneous second order linear ODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031336/sympy-extract-the-two-functions-solutions-of-a-homogeneous-second-order-linear), I want to get `u1` and `u2` as Function objects.
This way, I could use them in generic expressions, e.g., definite/indefinite integrals in user-defined functions, etc.
E.g., to calculate particular solutions of the ODE.
A workaround is shown below, but I see it clumsy, and possibly fragile.

This is what I have

```
>>> print(u1)
>>> print(type(u1))
>>> print(u2)
>>> print(type(u2))

1/r
<class 'sympy.core.power.Pow'>
r
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

I want to define

```
p = sym.Function('p', real=True)
def a1_par(u1, p):
    # From the standard form, g(r) = p'(r)
    R = sym.symbols('R', real=True, positive=True)
    g = sym.diff(p(R), R)
    # This would not work, since u1 is already a function of r
    # I need a Function object, so I can use u1(R) in the integrand
    #a1 = sym.integrate(u1*g, (R, 0, r)).doit()    # not useful
    a1 = sym.integrate(u1.subs(r,R)*g, (R, 0, r)).doit()    # workaround
    return a1
```

In fact, the parameter I am passing to `a1_par` is a function of `r`, not merely a Function object. If `u1` were a function object, my integration line would read

```
    a1 = sym.integrate(u1(R)*g, (R, 0, r)).doit()
```

Moreover, the return value of `a1_par` is again a function of `r`.
I would like to get a "handle" to the function (a Function object), so I can use it in other calculations.

**Related**:

1. [How to define a mathematical function in SymPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100053/how-to-define-a-mathematical-function-in-sympy)
2. 

Comment: Why are you defining `g(r) = p'(r)` with `R`? Wouldn't `a1` be the integral of functions of `r` from 0 to `R`?

Comment: @jared - No. The upper limit of integration is my variable of interest. `R` is a dummy integration variable, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021828/sympy-integral0-r-b-r-not-simplifying-to-zero-when-stemming-from-the-lei).